# Variable Inspector (from nb extensions) doesn't work in Jupyter Notebook 5.6.0

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I'm working with Jupyter Notebook 5.6.0 and I would like to use the Variable Inspector from the [nb-extensions](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/varInspector/README.html). It's the newest version 0.5.0, I just installed it.

No matter if I enable the Variable Inspector via Anaconda Prompt or the Extensions Configurator, the icon that is meant to appear in the toolbar just doesn't show up. With other icons, for example datestamper, it works just fine.

Has anyone had this issue and knows how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, tried everything and when I switched from internet explorer to 
chrome, variable inspector icon finally showed up.